# Mapping microservices on frontend

Tags: url-rewriting, architecture, microservices

This is probably a bit opinion-based question, but I will try to be technical to still be relevant.

Consider having several microservices: `a`, `b`, `c`.

To make this available on frontend, these could be made available as:

- `https://host/services/a`
- `https://host/services/b`
- `https://host/services/c`

However, the fact that the endpoints are split between differents services are kind of irrelevant for frontend and basically if we can guarantee the endpoints don't clash, it would be great to have these available directly:

- `a/endpoint1` -> `https://host/services/endpoint1`
- `a/endpoint2` -> `https://host/services/endpoint2`
- `b/endpoint3` -> `https://host/services/endpoint3`
- `c/endpoint4` -> `https://host/services/endpoint4`

To implement such mapping, one needs to list all endpoint or at least write some matching pattern within the proxy service. This is very nice for the Frontend team to work with, however it is unfortunately very easy to brake.

What are the best practices for mapping the urls of microservices? Only thing which comes to my mind are some exports of OpenApi, which could be handled by FE to get the right path. However, every service generates its own OpenApi json, so we are basically back to the original problem.

Comment: have you checked https://github.com/Netflix/zuul ?

Answer (score 1):

are you sure the Frontend team needs ALL the exposed endpoints? Usually, frontends talk with an API Gateway, or, as cool kids call them these days, "Backend for Frontends".

In a nutshell, it's a special service that takes care of exposing only the functionalities/endpoints needed by the frontend. It will forward calls to the relevant services or, if necessary, call multiple services and aggregate the results.

In most cases these API Gateway don't have a db, as they're retrieving all the data from other services. They might however make use of a caching layer to speedup things.

You can even have multiple API Gateway, one per Frontend (eg. desktop, mobile).